# usage of "the" - "listen to the TV", or "listen to TV"

Tags: articles, definite-articles, zero-article

Question:

When we only listen to the sound of that machine (TV), not watching its screen, which is appropriate to say "listen to the TV" or "listen to TV"?

Background:

When we watch that machine, we say "watch TV"; and when we put it work, we say "turn on the TV." I think these usage indicate that we use "the" when the object is material thing not function. But we say "listen to the radio" or "listen to the music", so I wonder about the question stated above.

Comment: Generic vs, particular. If my wife is watching a programme on the TV, and I am nearby at the computer desk, I might _listen to the TV_ (set, in our living room). If I were blind, which, thankfully, I am not, I could say that I can only _listen to TV_.

Comment: Not a duplicate. 'Watch TV' is a fixed phrase, a very strong collocation. 'Listen to the TV', a far less common collocation (if it qualifies at all) probably models after 'listen to the radio'. Few people would use it unless there were a particular occasion being referred to ("I was in the kitchen, listening to the TV").

Comment: Is it going too far sideways to suggest ’I like TV/theatre/radio’ are all exactly equivalent, but giving each an article separates them?

Doesn’t ’the TV’ usually refer either to the specific item in your living room, or the technology, while ‘the theatre/radio’ also refer to the concept enclosing both?

Perhaps because TV is more obviously both a neologism and a contrived term, ‘the TV’ doesn’t come anywhere near as close to its root as do ‘the theatre/radio’.

Whether the given article is definite adds further nuance.